# why the detached entity is modified successfully in entity framework 5?

Tags: database, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, database-first

my code is .

```
class Program
        {

            static NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities();

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
       Order updateorder = new Order() { OrderID = 10256, ShipCountry = "444", ShipCity = "tehran" };            
                update(updateorder);
            }


            static public void update(Order updateorder)
            {

                context.Entry<Order>(updateorder ).State = EntityState.Modified;

                context.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
```

please help me , i confused why the detached entity is modified in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the call to `context.Entry<Order>(updateorder)` attaches the object to EF.